# Are there any approaches in machine learning (neural or otherwise) that can learn relations/non-deterministic functions?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, nlp

A lot of the approaches in machine learning (specifically natural language processing) to me seem to be focused on inferring the "most likely" output based on a given input. For instance, in training a neural net to parse natural language sentences, as I understand it, the corpora is annotated such that for each input sentence, there is exactly one parsed representation.

So a neural-net trained parser (for instance) would only be able to obtain a single parse of a sentence like "I killed the man with the spoon" when in fact this sentence (like many sentences in natural language) is ambiguous, and has multiple possible parses with different semantic interpretations.

This seems problematic to me for many natural language understanding problems -- for instance, if a user is trying to communicate with a chatbot, and what they are trying to say in unclear (due to a syntactic or other kind of ambiguity), they would not be able to ask for clarification from the user, but rather be tied to a single parse based on the output from the model.

Are there any machine learning techniques that are used in natural language processing to get around this problem? I've heard of relational neural nets, but I don't think that's exactly what I'm looking for here -- or at least I don't directly see how I would apply them to this sort of problem.

What I'm looking for is rather than training a model `raw_tokenized_sentence -> parse_tree`, I'd want to train a model more like

```
raw_tokenized_sentence -> list_of_parse_trees_with_probabilities_of_how_likely_a_parse_they_are
```

Has anyone specifically in the field of natural language processing looked into such things? And if not, is there some kind of machine learning algorithm which would be able to learn a non-deterministic function like this that I desire?

Something similar to this can be done with more procedural approaches where from a sentence, you can construct an algorithm returning a list of all possible parses (something I've implemented before for various grammars/lexicons), but the machine-learning approach to this problem has a lot of advantages, as it is not entirely clear how a notion such as *the probability of a parse* would be determined without training on real-world data.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I haven't used parsers for a long time so I don't know the recent tools. But from what I remember, probabilistic parsers actually work as you describe: they find all the possible parses with their associated probability, and then output the top N most likely parses. Often one has to use an option in order to get N>1, i.e. to get the other parses after the most likely one. I doubt that modern neural parsers wouldn't have such an option, and I'm sure that traditional ones do.